# XORing two hex strings in Python - which method is correct?

Tags: python, string, hex, ascii, xor

I've been struggling to find a way to XOR two hex numbers stored in strings correctly for a couple of days now, and I have come across two methods, both of which make sense to me but produce different results. I am not that versed in Python (as in, I have like 3 days of experience :D), so I cannot figure out which method is correct.

Method 1:

```
s1 = #hex number stored in a string 1
s2 = #hex number stored in a string 2

#Decoding the hex strings into ASCII symbols
s3 = s1.decode('hex')
s4 = s2.decode('hex')

#strxor - see the next code segment for the code of this function
xor1 = strxor(s3, s4)

#Encode the result back into ASCII
xor2 = xor1.encode('hex')
```

strxor function:

```
#This was given in my assignment and I am not entirely sure what is going on in
#here. I've been told that it takes two ASCII strings as input, converts them to
#numbers, XORs the numbers and converts the result back to ASCII again.

def strxor(a, b):     
    if len(a) > len(b):
        return "".join([chr(ord(x) ^ ord(y)) for (x, y) in zip(a[:len(b)], b)])
    else:
        return "".join([chr(ord(x) ^ ord(y)) for (x, y) in zip(a, b[:len(a)])])
```

Method 2:

```
s1 = #ciphertext 1 - hex number in a string
s2 = #ciphertext 2 - hex number in a string

#convert the string to integers, xor them
#and convert back to hex
xor = hex(int(s1, 16) ^ int(s2, 16))
```

As I said before, to my limited brain these two solutions seem identical, yet they produce completely different results. What is the problem? I have both Python 2.7.3 and 3.3.2 on my system, and I've tried both (although not for method 1, as python 3 no longer has the decode function for strings)

Answer (score 3):

`your_string.encode('hex')` will replace each character of `your_string` with its ASCII value using hexadecimal.

For instance, knowing that the 'A' letter is 0x41 in ASCII:

```
>>> 'AAAA'.encode('hex')
'41414141'
```

and you can do the other way using `decode`:

```
>>> '41414141'.decode('hex')
'AAAA'
```

but that's not what you really want. What you want is 0x12 to be converted into 18 (16 + 2). And to do that, the correct way is to use `int(your_string, 16)` to interpret your_string as a number encoded in base 16.

So, the correct solution is the last one.

```
xor = hex(int(s1, 16) ^ int(s2, 16))
```

`s1` and `s2` are strings containing the hexadecimal representation of your numbers, you decode them into `int` telling Python it's base 16. Then you do the xor and finally you convert it back into a string using the hexadecimal representation (with `hex`).

Comment: You seem to be the one who understood my problem the best, and I understand the problem now :D. Too bad I can't vote your comment up as I am new to the forums.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate issue with the first method is that you're applying `strxor` to `s1` and `s2`:

```
xor1 = strxor(s1, s2)
```

whereas you probably meant `s3` and `s4`:

```
xor1 = strxor(s3, s4)
```

With this change, I get identical results from both methods (on a simple test case).

Comment: Your test cases weren't complete enough as `strxor` is quite buggy.

Comment: That was a derp on my part :D. But in my own code, this mistake is not present.

Answer (score 0):

> ...these two solutions seem identical, yet they produce completely different results. What is the problem?

To me the results are the same:

```
def strxor(a, b):
    len_ = min(len(a), len(b))
    return "".join([chr(ord(x) ^ ord(y)) for (x, y) in zip(a[:len_], b[:len_])])


def work(s1, s2):
    #strxor - see the next code segment for the code of this function
    xor1 = strxor(s1.decode('hex'), s2.decode('hex')).encode('hex')

    #convert the string to integers, xor them
    #and convert back to hex
    xor2 = hex(int(s1, 16) ^ int(s2, 16))[2:]

    print xor1
    print xor2

work('A0', '0A')
work('A0', 'A0')
work('00', 'AA')
work('00A0', 'A000')
```

gives:

```
aa
aa
00
0
aa
aa
a0a0
a0a0
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you define test cases that you know the answers to. For example:

```
0x0f0f0f ^ 0xf0f0f0  -> 0xffffff
0x101010 ^ 0x000000  -> 0x101010
```

and so on. Your "Method 2" is valid and correct and is legal in Python 2 and 3 (but you should make sure your test cases confirm this).

The function `strxor` is defective as your tests will show. It takes two input strings converts the corresponding character in each string to its `ord`inal representation, XORs them together, converts that back to ASCII with `chr` and joins the whole mess together again. One test case is needed to show that it might work fine for decimal digits but bombs on mixed case hexadecimal:

```
strxor('b', 'B')
```

should not yield `#`.

Method 2 is the cleanest by far, using `str.decode` could be considered codec abuse when `hex` and `int` are already there. The instructor might have been more interested in [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), but there are far better examples that could have been chosen.